# Python "commands out of sync" error message when I am trying to import csv to MYSQLdb

Tags: python, csv, mysql-python

I've get this error message when i want to execute my sqldb code in Python 2.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/air18-mysql.py", line 52, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 221, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 107, in _warning_check
    warnings = self._get_db().show_warnings()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 371, in show_warnings
    self.query("SHOW WARNINGS")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 282, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

The relevant pieces of my code are as follows:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ 
   CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `A` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `B` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `E` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `F` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `G` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ load data local infile 'C:/Python27/output.csv' 
into table test
character set latin1
fields terminated by ';'
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n';
ignore 1 lines;
"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

I tried it with another csv too and it worked.
Maybe there is a problem in my csv file or i can't imagine what is the problem with this.

Here one part of my csv file (in NotePad++):

```
"apple apricot";" avocado";"blackcurrant (fruit)-";"blackberry";"blueberry (fruit) ";"";"lemon lime"
"quince pear";" banana";"papaya (fruit)-";"orange";"passion fruit (fruit) ";"";"pineapple watermelon"
```

Comment: Not confirm but, you can try with changing the connection as connection1 and cursor with cursor1 while creating the connection for the second time. Same as like `connection1 = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor1 = connection1.cursor()`

Comment: I tried it, i have got the same problem

Comment: What is line 52?

Comment: cursor.execute(query)

Comment: Have you tried to do this manually? if not try to create and insert the same manually in mysql server directly?

Comment: I tried it in this moment :D i created the table manually and i just run the insert into code..but i get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

after lemon lime and pineapple watermelon, you are missing a semi colon. Try with this:

```
"apple apricot";" avocado";"blackcurrant (fruit)-";"blackberry";"blueberry (fruit) ";"";"lemon lime";"quince pear";" banana";"papaya (fruit)";"orange";"passion fruit (fruit) ";"";"pineapple watermelon";
```

Comment: but lemon line and pineapple watermelon are the ends of my lines (and this is a web-scraping dataes), so it is more complaceted if i want to modify the csv. i think there is a good way to read it into mysqldb directly, but i dont know why i get this error message..

Comment: if you can not guarantee the structure/format for CSV, and if there's a slight chance of invalid CSV, read CSV programmatically and format it, then import it into database